# How to invoke executable in remote container / computer

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, remote

### What I have

- Web App that invokes executables on demand in separate process like `WordToPdfConverter.Exe`. Inputs are cli arguments and files passed as cli arguments, output is standard/error output. The process is generally short lived.
- Single server setup where the executables runs on the same machine like web server
- Currently the executables can affect the web app performance or cause out of memory exception, etc...

### What I need

- I'm about to dockerize the app using Windows Containers.
- I want to invoke the `WordToPdfConverter.Exe` processes in separate container.

### Question

How do I invoke the external executable remotely from my web app?

1. Should I wrap the CLI in some Http API? Maybe there is already existing solution to do exactly this
2. Can I just ssh into the remote container when invoking the command
3. Any other ideas?